# how to display data from a sql table into a JComboBox?

Tags: java, prepared-statement, jcombobox

**I want to display two column of my database into two JComboBox**

```
String rq1 = "SELECT region  FROM  rg";

String rq2 = "SELECT ACTELS  FROM  rg";

st1 = conn.createStatement();
st2 = conn.createStatement();
rs1 = st1.executeQuery(rq1);
rs2 = st2.executeQuery(rq2);   

comboBox_ACTELS = new JComboBox<String>();
comboBox_gouver = new JComboBox<String>();

while ((rs1.next())&&(rs2.next())) {
    String m1= rs1.getString("region");
    String m2= rs2.getString("ACTELS");
    //comboBox_gouver.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {m1}));
    //comboBox_ACTELS.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {m2}));
    comboBox_gouver.addItem(m1);
    comboBox_ACTELS.addItem(m2);
    nbp ++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opps, this can be done much simpler as both are from same table 'rg'

```
String rq1 = "SELECT region,ACTELS FROM rg";

st1 = conn.createStatement();
rs1 = st1.executeQuery(rq1);  

comboBox_ACTELS = new JComboBox<String>();
comboBox_gouver = new JComboBox<String>();

while (rs1.next()) {
  String m1= rs1.getString("region");
  String m2= rs1.getString("ACTELS");
  //comboBox_gouver.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {m1}));
  //comboBox_ACTELS.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new String[] {m2}));
   comboBox_gouver.addItem(m1);
   comboBox_ACTELS.addItem(m2);
    nbp ++;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I have two class